# How to recreate fragments (onCreate) in paging using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

I'm stuck in a weird situation where I want the fragments to be recreated when paging is performed. I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

For example if I use 2 seekbars in 2 different fragments, I want the seekbar in second fragment to update itself according to the value of seekbar in the first fragment.

Without the paging method I'm using a static global variable that updates the seekbars when the fragments are created.

So when I use action bars with tabs i get expected results becasue when I cahnge tabs the fragments are created newly each time.

Now if I use paging method to swipe between these 2 fragments, the fragment states are retained and they dont update as expected becasue the onCreate is not called at all.

I've used

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

in my extended `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` Class but no use.

What's the work around for this.

Please help!